# Could you keep writing without knowing what's the theme?

Tags: theme

Now before you give me the answer 'That is basically impossible' I would like to explain my situation.

What I learn from school is that a theme is a lesson or the main idea to the reader. That is the basic way of explaining it.

Though I got my plot and genre ready, I still haven't got the faintest clue about what lesson my book would teach. Is it possible to write without one? Or do I continue writing, hoping that one would arouse without me being aware of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  It is perfectly possible to write a story through without figuring out what it is about.  Indeed, C.S. Lewis famously advised:

> But it is better not to ask the question at all. Let the pictures tell you their own moral. For the moral inherent in them will rise from whatever spiritual roots you have succeeded in striking during the whole course of your life. But if they don’t show you any moral, don’t put one in.

Comment: Theme, as one of my teachers pointed out, is for the reader to figure out, not the author. It's your job to tell a good story. Getting hung up on theme can tend to produce a story that's rather preachy.